# My picturebox's are not getting completely round

Tags: vb.net, picturebox

After following a video trying to get rounded picture-box's in visual basic, the
Box wont get completely round, I have been increasing vales and it is not working correctly, can somebody show what I did wrong

```
Public Sub RoundShape(ByVal ctl As System.Windows.Forms.Control, Optional ByVal CirRay As Single = 125.0!)
    Dim gr As System.Drawing.Drawing2D.GraphicsPath = New System.Drawing.Drawing2D.GraphicsPath()
    gr.AddPie(5, 5, CirRay, CirRay, 180.0!, 90.0!) 'Top left Corner'
    gr.AddPie(ctl.Width - CirRay, 5, CirRay, CirRay, 270.0!, 90.0!) 'Top Right Corner'
    gr.AddPie(5, ctl.Height - CirRay, CirRay, CirRay, 90.0!, 90.0!) 'Bottom left corner'
    gr.AddPie(ctl.Width - CirRay, ctl.Height - CirRay, CirRay, CirRay, 0.0!, 90.0!) 'Bottom right corner'


    gr.AddRectangle(New Rectangle(2, CirRay / -2, CirRay / -2, ctl.Height - CirRay))
    gr.AddRectangle(New System.Drawing.Rectangle(-1, CirRay / -2, CirRay / -2, ctl.Height - CirRay))
    gr.AddRectangle(New Rectangle(ctl.Width - CirRay / -1, CirRay / -1, CirRay / 2, ctl.Height - CirRay))

    ctl.Region = New Region(gr)
End Sub
```

Edit: link to the reference video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vD3XDU0X1Gk

Edit: okay I edited the code so I am a lot closer to getting a completely round picture-box but now there is a straight down the middle and don't see how to push the to object together

Edit: The picture-box get's mostly Complete When I take

```
Public Sub RoundShape(ByVal ctl As System.Windows.Forms.Control, Optional ByVal CirRay As Single = 125.0!)
```

and then change the the picture-box's size to 130, 130, but I can't anchor it down or do anything to the size without breaking, is there some way to make it completely round based off the picture-box's height and width or do I just change the

```
Single = 125.0!
```

value and just try and work with it from there?

Comment: Are you coding in ComicSans in that video?  Ouch.

Comment: I am not the one coding that is the reference video

Comment: You can comment out various lines of your solution to learn which parts are already drawing properly and which need tweaking.

Comment: I have but the only thing controlling Roundness are the      `AddRectangle`

Comment: Is this still an issue?  (Note: when replying, include @miroxlav into comment so I'll get notified)

Comment: yes and still checking it I still don't know what specific to do @miroxlav